# If I change my name, do my contacts see?

Tags: gmail, google-account

I would like to change the name associated with my Google account, and for various reasons I'd rather a few contacts didn't know about it. What I wonder is when I change my name in Gmail, does it change for my existing contacts or do they retain the name they had saved for me?

Answer (score 2):

Changing the name on your account will not change what other people may have listed for you in their contacts list (whether it's Google Contacts or not).

That's not to say that if you send them an email message they wouldn't see your new name; they certainly will.